# Form feedback without a page refresh

Tags: php, forms

I'm getting my feet wet with form processing so bear with me. I have a basic HTML form and a script that sends mail. At the moment it sends and refreshes to give feedback. What I would like is if the feedback could be given without refreshing the page.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>E-Mail Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="beta_sendmail.php" method="POST">
<p><strong>Name: </strong><br/>
<input type="text" size="25" name="name" /></p>
<p><strong>E-Mail Address: </strong><br />
<input type="text" size="25" name="email" /></p>
<p><strong>Message: </strong><br />
<textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="send" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the PHP

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Mail Sending Script</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "<p>Thank you, <b>".$_POST["name"]."</b>, for your message!</p>";
echo "<p>Your email address is: <b>".$_POST["email"]."</b>.</p>";
echo "<p>Your message was: <br/>";
echo $_POST["message"]."</p>";
//start building the mail string
$msg = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\n";
$msg .= "E-Mail: ".$_POST["email"]."\n";
$msg .= "Message: ".$_POST["message"]."\n";
//set up the mail
$recipient = "mailto@me.com";
$subject = "Form Submission Results";
$mailheaders = "From: My Web Site <defaultaddress@yourdomain.com> \n";
$mailheaders = "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"];
//send the mail
mail($recipient, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For this you need AJAX. Start searching around here and for basic AJAX tutorials.  JavaScript libraries (in particular jQuery) make it very easy to get started...

Comment: Has your question been answered?  We'll need feedback if not.

Comment: So far I've only got as far as marking up those helpful answers. Once I've worked through the answers and suggestions I'll let you know ;)

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their advice. Some great stuff in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jQuery, as @Michael suggested, and which I also recommend, here is a great tutorial to do exactly that: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

In essence there are 3 parts:

1) HTML Form

2) Javascript/jQuery

- Handles form submit event. You can do client side validations here, and if satisfied, submit the form via AJAX to your php script for processing.

3) PHP script

- Handles server side processing of the form. Returns data back to your javascript so you can continue processing and do whatever you need to do from there.

Comment: This is a great tutorial provided that you already have a sendmail script like the one above.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to start learning AJAX. Its purpose accomplishes exactly what you are doing. It stands for Asynchronous Javascript And XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can go 2 ways:

1.) to look into some JavaScript, that does the job for you, most likely `AJAX`, via `jQuery` or `Dojo` or, if you are a masochist, by hand.

2.) Have an `iframe` somewhere in your page and make your form `target` be the iframe - this could be the part of the page carrying the form - so the biggest part of the page would stand still, while the form is replaced by the "thankyou" message.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna start getting into AJAX.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/16/50-excellent-ajax-tutorials/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use jQuery.  Something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var dataString = 'postVariableName=' + $("postVariableValue").val() + '&postVariableName=' + $("postVariableValue").val();

    //alert (dataString);return false;   //to check the string being sent 
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST", 
        url: "postPath.php",
        data: dataString,  
        success: function(data) {
            //create jquery object from the response html
            var $response=$(data);

            //query the jq object for the values
            var title = $response.filter('div#title').text(); //Check the resulting post page output for a div with an ID of "title", and put it's text into a variable called "title"
            var cbody = $response.filter('div#cbody').html(); //Check the resulting post page output for a div with an ID of "cbody", and put it's html into a variable called "cbody"

            $("input#title").val(title); //Display the title on the page
            $("div#cbody").html(cbody); //Display the cbody on the page
        }
    });
});
```